# Oracle Partition based on other table data

Tags: oracle, partitioning

I have two table

```
1.  Order
2.  Payout_bank
```

According to our business order happens on date and “payout_bank” of that transaction happens 2 or more days after the transaction of order.

Now I would like to partition Order table based on date say 1stJan2018. So two partition.
I would like to partition Payout_bank based on the transactionNumber of order of 1stJan2018 or after 1st Jan 2018 in partition one and rest in other partition.

Note we have to do this as we would be dumping the older partion to archival database, so we want the referential integrity of our data in archival database.

Question : how can we define the partition of Payout_bank table?

Comment: Have a look at Referencing Partitioning, it might be want you need. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-54D18B18-6838-4115-9389-E1FB0D20A8CA.htm)

Comment: Have a look at [Reference Partitioning](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-54D18B18-6838-4115-9389-E1FB0D20A8CA.htm) and [Creating Reference-Partitioned Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-5E5BAB95-DE89-41CB-A61F-16A23A7A3B84.htm#VLDBG1280)

Comment: Add (partial, only relevant columns) table definitions if you want concrete suggestions; otherwise check ref partitions as suggested in the other comments.

Comment: Reference Partitioning can't be applied on interval based partitioning according to this article, My case is interval based partitioning>>http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_11g_new_reference_partitioning.htm

Comment: If you want a partition per day you could use list partition on value of say `date '2018-01-18'` - assuming you have a transaction date column which doesn't contain a time element. Obviously you'll need to add partitions procedurally, which is less convenient than interval partitioning. Like any other design decision, it's a trade-off.